# ExtJs doesn't create all files in directory - Error: Cannot find module '<path>\modern-app-3\node_modules\@sencha\ext\package.json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, extjs

So I am trying to create a new ExtJs project by following the steps [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/guides/getting_started/getting_started_with_npm.html).

After installing ext-gen, I tried creating a new app (using `ext-gen app -a -t moderndesktop -n ModernApp3` command) and I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '<path>\ExtJs3\modern-app-3\node_modules\@sencha\ext\package.json'
```

[image]

And my app folder looks like this (the node_modules folder only contains @jridgewell folder):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

```
npm -v
9.7.2

node -v
v18.16.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The terminal says that your application doesn't have ext-gen. And in node_modules you say that doesn't have anything besides @jridgewell folder.

I recommend you delete node_modules and after that use `npm install -g @sencha/ext-gen` again.

Hope it helps!